# Cube Translation Looks All Wrong

Tags: c#, matrix, transformation, opentk

I'm making a very simple cube in OpenTK and it seemed to be going fine until I tried to move it around. Moving it along the X Axis seems to elongate the cube, not the result I hoped for.

**My Vertex Shader**

```
#version 330

in vec3 vPosition;
in  vec3 vColor;
out vec4 color;
uniform mat4 modelview;
void
main()
{
    gl_Position = modelview * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
    color = vec4( vColor, 1.0);
}
```

**My Fragment Shader**

```
#version 330

in vec4 color;
out vec4 outputColor;

void
main()
{
    outputColor = color;
}
```

**How I make** `modelview`

```
    Matrix4 c = Matrix4.LookAt(Game.camera.Position, new Vector3(Game.camera.X + 1f, 0, Game.camera.Z + 0f), new Vector3(0, 1, 0)) * Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
    (float)(0.5 * Math.PI),
    (float)1366 / 768,
    0.1f,
    1000.0f); * Matrix4.CreateTranslation(Origin);
GL.UniformMatrix4(Game.uniform_mview, false, ref c);
```

[image: What I'm doing here is adding 0.01 to Origin.X while moving the camera the opposite direction]

What I'm doing here is adding 0.01 to Origin.X while moving the camera the opposite direction.

Does anyone know why it produces this result? Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT: Multiplied matrices by perspective * view * model**

[image]

This weird line seems to blink in and out as I move the camera around.

**EDIT 2: Matrix Printout**

```
(0, 0.9999995, 0.001019571, 0.001019367)
(0, 0.001019367, -1.0002, -0.9999995)
(0.5622255, 0, 0, 0)
(1207.66, -0.9999995, 980.9957, 980.9995)
```

Comment: are the marices in the correct order?  I'd usually expect perspective * view * model...

Comment: @realUser404 apologies, I wasn't referring to that, I meant the modelview in the question above, i.e. c = lookat * proj * trans.  I'd usually expect it to be something like proj * lookat * trans

Comment: Sorry for the delay on getting back to you guys, it's 6:52AM here. I will try switching my matrices around, see if that works.

Comment: I just switched the matrices around, and I'm getting a weird green line that blinks on and off, I'll post a gif.

Comment: seems like a weird result.  Another thing that may be a typo:

    1000.0f); * Matrix4.CreateTranslation(Origin);

is there supposed to be a semicolon before the * here?

Comment: also you are using OpenTK which uses transposed matrices by default (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452241/opentk-matrix-transformations)) which may explain the matrix weirdness.

Comment: Oh yeah, that was me removing commented out lines in my code, not what I had written in the actual code.

Comment: Okay I changed it back to `model*view*proj`, but now I'm just getting the same result again...

Comment: did u change back to the original, i.e lookat * proj * trans or did you try trans * lookat * proj

Comment: I tried trans * lookat * proj and I'm getting the result in the first gif

Comment: Can you somehow post the content of the modelview matrix?

Comment: How do you suggest I do that?

Comment: print the 4x4 float numbers in the matrix(s) to txt file/console/dubugoutput, then post them here.

Comment: Added matrix numbers.